# Is there a function to view donation information via YouTube Data API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am hoping to pull live stream donation information every 5 minutes onto my server. I am making a script to check that information for the names of the crew and send them payments automatically. Is there a way with the YouTube Data API to handle donation information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the YouTube apis support this functionality. The main issue is that the YouTube apis are more then ten years old.  They just give you basic access to the videos on YOuTube.

What you are looking for would be access to data used in the YouTube web app that being donations which is a relatively new future, and again part of the web app.  Not just video data.  Its just not something YouTube has released an api for yet.

Try and submit a feature request [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I agree, it seems there is a serious gap between features on the platform and the functionality of the API. I submitted a feature request report if anything comes of it, I will post it on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

As [DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72457741/7123660), the YouTube Data API v3 doesn't have such feature.

However I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/e52e69998c9188cdcf56b769e9c06f631facc005/lives.php#L37-L60) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by requesting https://yt.lemnoslife.com/lives?part=donations&id=VIDEO_ID you will get in `item["donations"]` the donations currently displayed in the YouTube live chat. Especially may interest you:

- Donation timestamp: `donation["timestampUsec"]` (example: `1654111675007219`)
- Donator channel id: `donation["authorExternalChannelId"]` (example: `UC_PkX-rSBPWJqoK2zRRalfQ`)
- Donation amount: `donation["purchaseAmountText"]["simpleText"]` (example: `100,00\u00a0$US`)
- Donation message: `donation["message"]["runs"][0]` (example: `FOR JUSTICE!`)

Comment: Thank you for your response and for the examples. I have sent a feature request to YouTube, but I am interested in talking about your API. I have sent a chat in your discord.

Comment: Benjamin, can you share the video_id you used in your answer? - I do remember watching donations on this video `RMABlI7TDbQ` , but, I don't get results with your endpoint `https://yt.lemnoslife.com/lives?part=donations&id=RMABlI7TDbQ`...

Comment: The video you shared isn't **a live being broadcasted with a chat displaying the donations**. I just tried again my endpoint with the video id `vJwyM5PR2kw` and it worked fine. The link you shared is now a *simple* video, so AFAIK there isn't anymore visible any donation (having a timestamp, channel id, amount and message).

Comment: If donations info is not exposed via API, how do lametric gets it?
https://lametric.com/en-US/legal/apps/donations-and-viewers-youtube-user-data-policy

Comment: @unxed
By API you mean YouTube Data API v3 (not my YouTube operational API), correct? As the website you shared doesn't look to promote open-source, we will never know how they make it work on their end. It's unclear if you have a problem using my open-source YouTube operational API for retrieving donations. Please let me know if it's the case. By the way just to make sure following MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes comment, by *gets it* you mean that LaMetric are able to retrieve donations for previous livestreams? If so, does it work for any livestream from any YouTuber?